# Local multi-player game using gamepads

Tags: c#, xna

I am making a local multi-player game on a PC with gamepads. I need to know when a player has pressed a button.

The code below doesn't work, but I need something similar to determine every button on the gamepad.

```
    public bool AButton(PlayerIndex playerIndex)
    {
        GamePadState newState = GamePad.GetState(playerIndex);
        if (newState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed  &&
                            oldState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Released)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

      oldState = newState;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize oldState to ButtonState.Released? If not, you will always return false.

But it will not work as intended because you are returning if the button is pressed or not. The oldState will not get stored as it is unreachable.